# svm.SVC predict giving different results for digit recognition

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, mnist

I'm running a digit recognition code from http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html . When running a baseline algorithm using support vector machine (sklearn.svm.SVC), I'm running into a weird problem.

```
# importing my libraries
DR_load_data as data_loader # for loading data

# importing third-party libraries
from sklearn import svm

def svm_baseline():

    training_data, validation_data, test_data = data_loader.load_data()
    # 70:30 random split for training_data and validation_data

    # train

    clf = svm.SVC()

    clf.fit(training_data[0], training_data[1])
    print "Fit completed."

    # getting prediction on validation sample

    predictions = [int(a) for a in clf.predict(validation_data[0])]

    # number of correct predictions
    num_correct = sum(int(a == y) for a, y in zip(predictions, validation_data[1]))

    print "Baseline classifier using an SVM."

    print "%s of %s values correct." % (num_correct, len(validation_data[1]))

    return clf

svm_baseline = svm_baseline()
```

This gives the following output:

```
Fit completed.
Baseline classifier using an SVM.
1397 of 12600 values correct.
```

As I'm returning my classifier fit, and having my doubts about the number of correct predictions, I tried to repeat the predictions on validation data outside the function, like this:

```
training_data, validation_data, test_data = data_loader.load_data()

pred_val = [int(a) for a in svm_baseline.predict(validation_data[0])]

num_correct = sum(int(a == y) for a, y in zip(pred_val, validation_data[1]))

print "%s of %s values correct." % (num_correct, len(validation_data[1]))
```

and got the following output:

```
9289 of 12600 values correct.
```

I'm not sure what is happening here as the code I ran separately in the terminal is same as what the function is doing inside. I tried multiple times so as to generate different validation samples but the issue persists.

Edit : I have added the code and the data to a [git repository](https://github.com/DevaranoroZ/Digit-Recognition). I have sampled only 4000 from the original data and have removed the loading of test data as I have not put that csv in the repository.

PS.: There might be few bugs in the code, I apologise for them in advance.

Could you help me figure out what is happening here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add some data, to try and replicate the problem?

Comment: I have added the code and the data to a [git repository](https://github.com/DevaranoroZ/Digit-Recognition.git) .
I have sampled only 4000 from the original data and have removed the loading of test data as I have not put that csv in the repository.
PS.: There might be few bugs in the code, I apologise for them in advance.